# Stop sound in HTML5 canvas in animate cc

Tags: javascript, actionscript, html5-canvas, animate-cc

The setup is 2 frames,

**first** frame there's a menu and 1 type of background music

**second** frame there's a different menu and another type of background music

Placing the background music is easy, the problem is, after I've made the transition from frame 1 to frame 2 via a **button** the remaining of frame 1's music overlaps into frame 2's music (until it's over) is there a way to kill frame 1's music before `gotoAndStop(1)` ?

the 2 sound files are in the library named 'bgmusic1' and 'bgmusic2'.

thanks ahead!

Answer (score 0):

The answer, after thorough search, is creating a linkage for each sound instance, in your library, playing them using `createjs.Sound.Play("linkageName',0,0,0,1);` <-- this will make them also loop, then, using `createjs.Sound.Stop();` When I want them to stop, before playing the new instance.